# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded on constructor

Tags: javascript, constructor

I'm creating a simple class, but I get an error that I can't understand.
My class is very simple:

```
class Character {
    constructor(firstName, lastName, height){
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.height = height;
    }

    get firstName(){
        return this.firstName;
    }
    
    set firstName(newName){
        this.firstName = newName;
    }

}

const hombre = new Character("Pedro", "Blanch", 186);

console.log(hombre.firstName);
```

But when I run in terminal with **node script.js** I always get an
**RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded**
error....
Where is the mistake?

Thanks!

Comment: no need to specify `get` and `set` functions for your properties. https://jsfiddle.net/9rhba2wd/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ECMAScript (which defines JavaScript), when you declare a class method with `get` and/or `set` keyword, a what is known as a property *descriptor* is created, on the prototype object. What you have in your class is absolutely equivalent to the following code:

```js
Object.defineProperty(Character.prototype, "firstName", {
    get() { /* get first name */ }
    set(value) { /* set first name */ }
});
```

Both accomplish exactly the same thing -- accessing `firstName` on objects of class `Character`, no matter how or *from where*, will *always* invoke the "getter" method. Even in your constructor, `this.firstName = firstName;` will invoke the "setter" method!

So, when you have an object of class `Character`, let's call it `good_char` for example (`var good_char = new Character`), and evaluate `good_char.firstName` or `this.firstName` in one of the class methods (including any of `get` or `set` methods), the `get` function above will be called. That's all well and good -- that's what you want, right?

If said function attempts to evaluate `this.firstName`, that will naturally *again cause the same `get` function to be called* -- to get the value of the property, after all -- a *recursive* call, *without end* -- `get` is then called again, encounters `this.firstName`, calls itself, encounters `this.firstName`... and so on *ad infinitum*.

That's why the script interpreter tells you that it has run out of stack space -- the stack is what tracks what calls what, and in your case `get` calls itself recursively, exhausting stack space. The `RangeError` refers to the stack growing out of allowed *range*.

All this behaviour basically should tell you that you cannot have a property that seemingly uses another property *with the same name* -- they're both the *same* property, accessed *only* through the getter method and assigned with the setter method. It doesn't matter whether it's accessed "from inside" the class method -- as `this.firstName`, or "from outside" -- as `good_char.firstName` -- the `get` will be called to, well, *get* the value of the property as per the descriptor that was created. You can't get to any "actual", "true" value unless you implement it through *another* property or otherwise, *yourself*. The descriptor you create with `get` keyword or `Object.defineProperty` does *not* hide any underlying value provided to you that you can access.

This may be confusing to you if you come from another programming language background where "getter" property paradigm is implemented differently.

Practically, if you insist, you will need to encapsulate something like `_firstName` (doesn't matter what you call it, it's just a convention for this kind of programming pattern) behind your actual `firstName` property that uses `get` and/or `set`, yourself. That is a bit of an anti-pattern, however -- why do you need getter and setter methods for a property, when all they do is get some value (`_firstName`) value and set it?

See also [Object.defineProperty](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty).

Comment: Thank you, I am glad the answer turned out to be fitting. You should mark the answer as "accepted" (assuming you do accept it, of course), as is customary on Stack Overflow.

Comment: "Even in your constructor, `this.firstName = firstName;` will invoke the "getter" method!" no it won't. The issue is solely that `this.firstName` will invoke the setter, even from said setter. (There would be an issue also if they did call the getter, but currently they don't).

Comment: @Kaiido I think it was a blunder on my part -- I meant to say it will invoke the _setter_ method. There is, obviously, no need to obtain the value of the `firstName` _property_ on the object being constructed. Thanks for pointing it out so I could fix this.